# RxJS waiting for response before sending next command over UDP

Tags: rxjs, udp

I am currently working on a project where I send UDP commands to a Tello drone.
The problem is that it uses UDP and when I send commands too fast before the previous one hasn't finished yet, the second command/action doesn't take place. I am using RxJS for this project and I want to create a mechanism to wait for the response ("ok" or "error") from the drone.

My Idea is to have 2 different observables. 1 observable that is the input stream from the responses from the drone and one observable of observables that I use as a `commandQueue`. This `commandQueue` has simple observables on it with 1 command I want to send. And I only want to send the next command when I received the "ok" message from the other observable. When I get the "ok" I would complete the simple command observable and it would automatically receive the next value on the `commandQueue`, being the next command.

My code works only when I send an array of commands, but I want to call the function multiple times, so sending them 1 by 1.

The following code is the function in question, testsubject is an observable to send the next command to the drone.

```js
async send_command_with_return(msg) {
    let parentobject = this;

    let zeroTime = timestamp();
    const now = () => numeral((timestamp() - zeroTime) / 10e3).format("0.0000");

    const asyncTask = data =>
      new Observable(obs => {
        console.log(`${now()}: starting async task ${data}`);

        
        parentobject.Client.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
          dataa => {
            console.log("loool")
            obs.next(data);
            this.testSubject.next(data);
            console.log(`${now()}: end of async task ${data}`);
            obs.complete();
          },
          err => console.error("Observer got an error: " + err),
          () => console.log("observer asynctask finished with " + data + "\n")
        );
      });

    let p = this.commandQueue.pipe(concatMap(asyncTask)).toPromise(P); //commandQueue is a subject in the constructor

    console.log("start filling queue with " + msg);
    zeroTime = timestamp();
    this.commandQueue.next(msg);
    //["streamon", "streamoff", "height?", "temp?"].forEach(a => this.commandQueue.next(a));

    await p;

    // this.testSubject.next(msg);
  }

  streamon() {
    this.send_command_with_return("streamon");
  }

  streamoff() {
    this.send_command_with_return("streamoff");
  }

  get_speed() {
    this.send_command_with_return("speed?");
  }

  get_battery() {
    this.send_command_with_return("battery?");
  }
}

let tello = new Tello();
tello.init();

 tello.streamon();
 tello.streamoff();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish sending commands one at a time by using a simple subject to push commands through and those emissions through `concatMap` which will execute them one at a time.

Instead of trying to put all the logic in a single function, it will may be easier to make a simple class, maybe call it `TelloService` or something:

```js
class TelloService {
  private commandQueue$ = new Subject<Command>();
  
  constructor(private telloClient: FakeTelloClient) {
    this.commandQueue$
      .pipe(
        concatMap(command => this.telloClient.sendCommand(command))
      )
      .subscribe()
  }

  sendCommand(command: Command) {
    this.commandQueue$.next(command);
  }
}
```

When the service is instantiated, it subscribes to the `commandQueue$` and for each command that is received, it will "do the work" of making your async call.  `concatMap` is used to process commands one at a time.

Consumers would simply call `service.sendCommand()` to submit commands to the queue.  Notice commands are submitted one at a time, it's not necessary to submit an array of commands.

Here is a [working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66823177?file=index.ts) example.

---

To address your condition of waiting until you receive an `ok` or `error` response before continuing, you can use [`takeWhile()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile), this means it will not complete the observable until the condition is met.

To introduce a max wait time, you can use [`takeUntil()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) with [`timer()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) to end the stream if the timer emits:

```js
    this.commandQueue$
      .pipe(
        concatMap(command => this.telloClient.sendCommand(command).pipe(
          takeWhile(status => !['ok', 'error'].includes(status), true),
          takeUntil(timer(3000))
        ))
      )
      .subscribe()
```

Here's an updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66823177-b?file=index.ts).

Comment: Thank you for your response, But I don't find a way to make it work, in your example you have a timer of 1500ms and after that u send the next command, in my case I need to wait untill the socket observable returns a value "ok"/"error" before sending the next command. If I understand your code correctly I should only change that part of the code, being, the sendCommand of the fakeTelloclient

Comment: I made it work, now I have the problem that it won't send the command over UDP when it doesn't receives a response, In your example u don't have this problem because U use a timer, but in my case if I don't send any command for lets say 5 seconds, the input stream observable doesn't emit an "ok" so that the next value of the Queue can be send. in other words the commands are all in the Queue but they wait for a response before sending the next one

Comment: you can use `takeWhile` and `takeUntil` operators to control when you will stop listening to inner observables.  I've updated the answer with another example.